# How can I display my results in C#?

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I have a program see below

I made the method but I want to display it in the console 
and not on the easy way like console.writeline(str.length). I want using the method I made.

could someone help me please

thanks in advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "dit is een test 1,2,3";
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }

        public int CountAllNumbersAndChar(string str) 
        { 
            return str.Length; 
        }

    }
}
```

#### Update:

I have the following program now

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "this is a test 1,2,3";
            int length = CountAllNumbersAndChar(str);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.WriteLine(length);// met de methode maar kan handiger met onderstaand voor beeld
      // Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
       // int numbers = str.Count(Char.IsNumber); // de makelijkste makelijke manier 
        //Console.WriteLine(numbers);
        int countnumber = CountNumbers(str) ;
        Console.WriteLine(countnumber);
        int countwords = words(str);
        Console.WriteLine(countwords);


    }

    public static int CountAllNumbersAndChar(string str)
    {
        return str.Length;
    }
    public static int CountNumbers(string str)
    {
        return str.Count(Char.IsNumber);
    }
    public static int words(string str)
    {
        int words = str.Split().Count(str => str.All(Char.IsLetter));
    }
}
```

}

but it still doesnt work
could someone say me what I have to change ?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
Console.WriteLine(CountAllNumbersAndChar(str));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it. Note `public` ***`static`*** `int CountAllNumbersAndChar(string str)`  in the code below. You can't call `CountAllNumbersAndChar` from `Main` if you don't declare it as `static`.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "this is a test 1,2,3";
            int length = CountAllNumbersAndChar(str);    

            Console.WriteLine(length);
        }

        public static int CountAllNumbersAndChar(string str) 
        { 
            return str.Length; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ for all these tasks. Although I'm not sure you are familiar with it. It's really simple though, so have a look at the code and see if you can follow.

```
string str = "dit is een test 1,2,3";

// Length of the string
int chars = str.Length;

// LINQ: Count all characters that is a number
int numbers = str.Count(Char.IsNumber);

// LINQ: Split the string on whitespace and count the 
// elements that contains only letters
int words = str.Split().Count(s => s.All(Char.IsLetter));

Console.WriteLine(chars); // -> 21
Console.WriteLine(numbers); // -> 3
Console.WriteLine(words); // -> 4
```

Of course, the way I'm counting words there is not perfect, but it should get you started. For more accurate ways you should google it as there are hundreds of examples out there.

Comment: Have you included using for System.Linq?

Comment: Be sure to reference System.Core too. The code is really working, I don't know why you are saying otherwise.

Comment: I found the problem, but it is not related to any assembly, the auto complete does not display the extension method count for the string, but when I write it, it displays tool tip!!! strange

Comment: but again your code, count numbers incorrectly as numbers larger than 9 will cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to count number of numbers inside your string

```
      public int CountAllNumbersAndChar(string str)         
       {
           return  str.Split(new char[]{' ',','},
         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count    
         (
           x=>
           {
               int d;
               return int.TryParse(x,out d);
           }
        );   
       }
```

Comment: How is this better than `str.Count(Char.IsNumber)`? Also, please format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: str.Count will iterate on each character, for example 19 will be counted as 2 !!!

Comment: That is true. In that case you'd have to use something like your example, indeed.